# How to collect field values from case classes in scala

Tags: scala, traits

I've got various case classes with different fields inherit some trait. All are mixed in a List. What is the way to collect (or group by) specific field's values?

```
sealed trait Template

object Template {
  case class TemplateA(field: String) extends Template
  case class TemplateB extends Template
}

object Runner {
  def main(args: String*) {
    val list = List(TemplateA("abc"), TemplateB, Template("cde"))

    // need to output something like "abc;1", "cde;1"

  }
}
```

Comment: `groupMapReduce` and maybe better modelling _(the question is not very clear)_

Comment: question is that how can i in that groupMapReduce refer to the field that only present in one of the case class, but not in another, if list contains both types? @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez

Comment: Well, you may use pattern matching and a default value for all other cases that you then ignore, you may also `collect` before the `groupMapReduce` you may model the data differently as AminMal showed.

Comment: @glaz666 Why not `list.collect { case x: TemplateA => x.field }`? Or `groupBy`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Yeah this one's also a good idea I didn't think of! But personally, I'd rather have a list of some common type, rather than list of `Any`.

Comment: @AminMal I didn't propose `List[Any]`. Also I suspect OP missed `TemplateA extends Template` `TemplateB extends Template` part in the code.

Comment: @DmytroMitin That might be the case, also I didn't mean that you proposed `List[Any]`, I was talking about the modeling of the OP, in addition to your solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally agree with @LuisMiguel, just to show one way of doing this, here's what I can think of:

```scala
trait Template { val field: Option[String] } 
case class TemplateA(field: Option[String]) extends Template 
case class TemplateB() extends Template { override val field: Option[String] = None }

val list: List[Template] = List(
  TemplateA(Some("abc")),
  TemplateB(),
  TemplateA(Some("cde"))
)

list.collect { 
  case template if template.field.nonEmpty =>
    template.field.get
}.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)  

// res8: Map[String, Int] = Map("abc" -> 1, "cde" -> 1)
```

Or if you want to get rid of the Optional argument when instantiating `TemplateA` instances, you can also do this:

```scala
case class TemplateA(private val value: String) extends Template {
  override val field: Option[String] = Option(value)
}

val list: List[Template] = List(TemplateA("abc"), TemplateB(), TemplateA("cde"))
```

---

As @DmytroMitin mentioned, we can do a bit of refactoring to avoid using `if`s in our collect function, I'd rather use some sort of unapply function, that can extract the field value of `TemplateA` instances:

```scala
object Template { // or any name as you wish
  def unapply(t: Template): Option[String] = t match {
    case TemplateA(Some(value)) => Option(value)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

And then, we can use pattern matching:

```scala
list.collect {
  case Template(field) => field
}.groupMapReduce(identity)(_ => 1)(_ + _)
```

Comment: I guess code like like `case ... if opt.nonEmpty => ... opt.get ...` or `if (opt.nonEmpty) ... opt.get ... else ...` is an antipattern. Upon refactoring if-part can disappear and welcome, exception.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Yeah sure, my answer was focused about the modeling and the use of groupMapReduce, I'll update it.